# Does casting the ioctl argument break the strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, c99, strict-aliasing

I'm running a *Linux 3.2* kernel with the following `ioctl` prototype:

```
long ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);
```

I noticed that `arg` is always **unsigned long** regardless of the actual data type passed to `ioctl` from the respective userspace function. Examples for `ioctl` typically show the following implementation ([source](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/08/io-control-in-linux/)):

```
typedef struct
{
    int status, dignity, ego;
} query_arg_t;

#define QUERY_GET_VARIABLES _IOR('q', 1, query_arg_t *)

static long my_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
        query_arg_t q;

        switch (cmd)
        {
                case QUERY_GET_VARIABLES:
                        q.status = status;
                        q.dignity = dignity;
                        q.ego = ego;
                        if (copy_to_user((query_arg_t *)arg, &q, sizeof(query_arg_t)))
                        {
                                return -EACCES;
                        }
                        break;
                default:
                        return -EINVAL;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that a **query_arg_t *** type is expected, so a cast is applied: `(query_arg_t *)arg`

Doesn't this break the strict aliasing rule though, since `arg` is of type **unsigned long** while the cast is **query_arg_t ***?

Comment: It does, but it works and that's enough :P

Comment: I wonder if it doesn't though, since it's not the address which is cast, but the integer value itself. For example, would this break the strict alias rule: `(query_arg_t *)(42)`?

Comment: Oh, so that's it... no, it won't. I was confused by the title. What you are talking about is then not type punning (IIRC that would be `*(query_arg_t *)&some_unsigned_long_long`).

Comment: Oops, I suppose I should change the title to say "casting" rather than "type punning".

Comment: Were that a `uintptr_t` I would say no. As it is now, there is the assumption that `unsigned long` is large enough to hold a valid pointer type.

Comment: @WhozCraig That assumption is guaranteed valid by the ABI for this operating system.  (The code shown is part of an operating system kernel.  Kernel code often leans really hard on the rules, and in particular, relies on behavior that is formally undefined in the C standard but is well-defined taking into account *all* relevant standards, such as the ABI and the documented behavior of the system bus.)

Comment: Regardless, my concern isn't with whether the value in arg is valid, but the reordering that could occur if the strict aliasing rule is broken. The code could theoretically modify `arg` before the cast; though I can't think of a practical reason for doing such, it is a theoretical possibility and I would like to understand the resulting behavior.

Comment: If you modify `arg` before the cast, the compiler is *not* allowed to hoist accesses to the memory pointed-to by `arg` past the modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers are integral types. It's entirely fine to store a pointer in any integral type that is large enough to contain it. For example, the following is perfectly valid C:

```
double f()
{
    double a = 10.5;

    uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)(&a);

    double * q = (double *)p;

    return *q;
}
```

By contrast, the following is a clear aliasing violation:

```
short buf[100] = {};

double x = *(double*)(buf + 13);
```

The point is that it doesn't matter how you *store* your pointer values. What matters is that you must only treat those pointers as pointers to an object that *are* actually pointers to an object of the correct type.

In the first example, `p` does really store the pointer to a double, although it is not itself a `double *`. In the second example, `buf + 13` is simply not a pointer to a double, so dereferencing it as such is type punning, and an aliasing violation.

(Pointers and casts are one of the reasons that C is not a *safe* language: The correctness of an operation can depend on the *value* of a variable, rather than just its *type*.)

Comment: Your second example is not an aliasing violation, because of the "or a character type" exception to the aliasing rules.  It might be UB because the pointer is misaligned for `double`, though.  May I suggest `uint64_t l = 99; double x = *(double *)&l;` instead?

Comment: @Zack: I think it's the other way round: interpreting any object pointer as a char pointer is not an aliasing violation. (But I've changed the type.)

Comment: The way it's written, it doesn't *sound* like it, but the aliasing rules are intended to be symmetric.  The committee specifically didn't want to disallow the idiom of overlaying a structure on a `char` buffer.

Comment: `short x = (double*)(buf + 13);` are you really assigning a `double *` to a `short`? I think there is a typo here.

Comment: @ouah: Oh, sorry, I was missing the dereferencing, and my previous "correction" just made it worse. Thanks!

Comment: @KerrekSB in that case why are you using `short x = ` and not simply `double x =`, as the aliasing violation in your example comes anyway from the dereference operation.

Answer (score 2):

This does not break the aliasing rules.

Object `arg` is accessed only here in the `my_ioctl` function:

```
(query_arg_t *)arg
```

And the object is accessed only through its type `unsigned long`. The cast only converts the value of the object from an `unsigned long` value to a `query_arg_t *` value.

Comment: However, if the implementation first modifies `arg` (say `arg += 1`) for whatever reason before casting its value, wouldn't that give the compiler the opportunity to reorganize instructions, resulting in the casting coming before the modification?

Comment: No. Let's say you have `arg += 1` before. The implementation knows it has to perform this statement before reading `arg` in your `copy_to_user` function call. What you have is a simple evaluation of an `unsigned long` object followed by a cast operation; this has nothing to do with aliasing rules.

Comment: If you cast a pointer value to `uintptr_t`, do arithmetic on the value, cast it back to the pointer type, and then dereference it, the behavior is *implementation-defined* (**not** undefined).  §6.3.2.3p5: "An integer may be converted to any pointer type.  Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation."  The "might be" clauses license an implementation to define at least *some* such modified pointers as triggering UB at runtime if dereferenced.

Comment: ... however, because this is implementation-defined behavior, it is *not* compile-time undefined behavior, i.e. the compiler is *not* allowed to optimize on the assumption that you have not done this.

Comment: I see now what you mean: although the representation of the pointer may not be as expected due to the system on which the program is running, the C99 standard guarantees that these operations are valid and thus the compiler cannot assume they are independent instructions.

Comment: However, how do I know that the `uintptr_t` defined in [linux/types.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h?v=3.2#L44) actually has this C99 guarantee; isn't that only for the standard library `uintptr_t` defined in **/usr/include/stdint.h**?

Comment: `uintptr_t` is a `typedef` for some unspecified integer type with the property that a valid pointer can be cast to it, and back, without loss of information.  `typedef` names are just labels; the property of interconvertibility with pointers belongs to the *underlying integer type*.  And header files are not magic; they just contain more code.  Therefore, as long as whoever wrote `linux/types.h` did not make a mistake, its `uintptr_t` is just as good as the one from `stdint.h`.  And *so is `unsigned long`*, if you are on an ABI that says that that's the underlying type of `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that while these are aliases, they exist in entirely different execution contexts - the user space and the kernel. The strict aliasing rule is meant to prevent issues that can arise when the compiler deals with possible aliases in a unit of code. This never happens for user space and kernel space code. They are separate units of code, that never mix together in ways that can cause issues related to what the strict aliasing rule is meant to address.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned long` (or some other integer type which is cast-compatible with `unsigned long`) is the underlying type of `uintptr_t` in all Linux ABIs.

```
$ grep -rw uintptr_t /usr/include/stdint.h
typedef unsigned long int uintptr_t;
```

C99 says that any pointer type can be cast to `uintptr_t` (or its underlying type) and back *to the original pointer type* without loss of information or violation of the strict-aliasing rules.  So as long as the user space code that called `ioctl(fd, QUERY_GET_ARGS, ptr)` passed a `query_arg_t *` as the `ptr` argument, the program-as-a-whole is conformant.

Note also that the `ioctl` prototype you show is the in-kernel, driver-side interface.  In user space, the prototype is

```
extern int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long int request, void *arg);
```

which makes it more apparent that the third argument is some concrete but unspecified pointer type, and that caller and (ultimate) callee had better agree on the actual type of the pointer.  (That being the normal use pattern for `void *` in C.)

(Further note for pedants: the *actual* user space prototype is

```
extern int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long int request, ...);
```

This is a compatibility kludge for programs that pass numeric constants as the third argument without a cast.  You may be beginning to understand why `ioctl` is not considered a well-designed API anymore.)

Comment: I don't think `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to have an underlying type of **unsigned long** though.

Comment: @VilhelmGray TO my knowledge it isn't, but I'm not that well versed on that part of the spec, only that the **optional** type `uintptr_t`, if provided, is sufficient to hold true to the back-and-forth cast. Considering `uintptr_t` is not *required* to be provided by a standard-compliant implementation (C99 §7.20.1.4p1), ymmv.

Comment: @VilhelmGray The C standard does not guarantee that, but *all Linux ABIs* define `uintptr_t` either as `unsigned long` or as an unsigned integer type that is the same width and precision as `unsigned long` (e.g. when `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` are the same width, `uintptr_t` might be `unsigned int`).  Since this question is about the guts of `ioctl` on Linux, that's something that can be relied upon.

Comment: @Zack When you mention that the underlying type of uintptr_t can be used just as uintptr_t, do you mean this is implicitly true (rather than explicitly stated in the C99 spec) because uintptr_t is a typedef variable so this implies the underlying type must have the same property?

Comment: It is *explicitly* stated in C99 that: if the typedef `uintptr_t` is provided by the implementation, then *its underlying type* has the property of being interconvertible with pointers without loss of information. The exact wording is "[`uintptr_t`, if present, is a typedef for] an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back ...". The property belongs to the unsigned integer type, not the typedef name for it.